# multiple master pages for 1 calling page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

I have 2 master pages with same (href) links on top of the page. Now these links load on the same master page when clicked on (by requirement). The problem is both these master pages have same links, so basically the same page shall be loaded in the master page.
Now what i need is when the person is on Master Page 1 and clicks on the link it should load in the same page. Whereas if the user is on Master Page 2 and clicks on the same link, i should be able to change the master page from 1 to 2 and load that in Master Page 2. Something like DirectCast.
any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can switch the master page in the Page_PreInit event.  For more of an explanation check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

It would look like

```
    void _Default_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MasterPageFile = "NewMasterPage.master";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I fully understand your use case, but here are some ideas:

1. You could track which MasterPage the user is on through Session state, and use that to remember which MasterPage to show in subsequent visits.
2. If you can alter the hrefs slightly, you could use a query string to indicate which MasterPage should be utilized.
3. Depending on your application, you could store which MasterPage should be used in your database, tied to each user.

I assume you're dynamically switching MasterPages based on some logic, so it just comes down to choosing a method to store which MasterPage should be used.

Comment: ok, we're very close to answer. In referance to option 1, i think that might work. The case is the href links on both pages are the same page. So click on Master 1 or 2, shall open the same file. But how to dynamically change the master 1 to 2 or back to 1, for each link, thats what i wanted to know. I hope that will help you solve my problem.